# Import a working formula from a different Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I want to import a working formula from doc 1 to doc 2.

I used importrange but then it importet the data from doc 1 to doc 2 and not the formula.

I then used a second spreadsheet in doc 1 to show the formulas with the help of formulatext and then imported that second spreadsheet to doc 2. this correctly showed the formulas in doc 2 but it was treated as text and not as a formula and therefore didn’t start working.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In Sheet1, just click in the cell that contains the formula, then click Ctrl-C to copy to clipboard (or Cmd-C on a Mac).

In Sheet2, click on the cell where you want to place the formula and click Ctrl-V to paste (or Cmd-V on a Mac).

Comment: Well thanks. However, thats of course not what i meant. I should have put "I want to automatically import a working formula from doc 1 to doc 2"

Comment: I recommend that you edit your post to be clear about your goal. You said that my post is "of course" (i.e., obviously) not what you meant; but that is, in fact, what I thought you meant nonetheless as a professional of decades. So you will increase your chances of other volunteers helping you if you make your original post more specific. I will tell you that in order to copy a formula from sheet to sheet automatically will require use of a script. You haven't provided a link to the sheets or any specific sheet details, so that will be difficult for anyone to help you with.